# Best Practice to deploy Django with celery apps

Tags: django, celery

I'm developing the application that can broadcast messages periodically, and I have successfully developed and implemented it using django and celery locally using virtual environment. So right now I'm going to deploy it in my production. My questions are :

1. How can I set configuration for production using script ? I've configured it one time but it was at laravel and using deploy-er. But this time, my application is using django. So I don't get any idea about it.
2. How can I make the celery run in background service together and running well with my application when I deploy it ?

If you have any references about it, do you mind to share it with me ? so I can learn about it because I'm still confused on how to implement it.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tutorial for running django:

[How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

And this one to run celery in backgroud:

[How to Use Celery and RabbitMQ with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html)

You'll use uwsgi and nginx to run django and supervisor to run celery every time your server comes up.

Just be careful with the paths and you'll be fine (Usually people that are new with linux or django might get confused and use wrong paths for configs).

Celery can be run in different ways too:

[How to run celery as a daemon?](https://pythad.github.io/articles/2016-12/how-to-run-celery-as-a-daemon-in-production)

Good luck